# How to position child div to the center of every parents div using position absolute in css

Tags: html, css, css-position, vertical-alignment, centering

I'm having difficulty on positioning child div's on every parents div.

Here's the css code:

```
.mainDiv {
   height:500px;
   position: relative;
}

.mainDiv .parent1 {
  height: 250px;
  background-color: blue;
  top: 50px;
  position: relative;
}

.mainDiv .parent2 {
  height: 250px;
  background-color: yellow;
  position: relative;
}


.mainDiv .parent1 .sub1 {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: green;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  top: 50%;
}

.mainDiv .parent2 .sub2 {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  top: 50%;
}
```

Here's the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/aldrin27/8Lcx1y5r/)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use transform for that to the child div and it will work!

```
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
```

snippet below:

```css
.mainDiv {
  height:500px;
  
  position: relative;
}

.mainDiv .parent1 {
  height: 250px;
  background-color: blue;
   position: relative;
}

.mainDiv .parent2 {
  height: 250px;
  background-color: yellow;
   position: relative;
}


.mainDiv .parent1 .sub1 {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: green;

  position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    
}

.mainDiv .parent2 .sub2 {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="mainDiv">
  <div class="parent1">
    <div class="sub1">
        
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="parent2">
    <div class="sub2">
      
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: should i remove the `margin-left:  and margin-right: auto` ?

Comment: yes, and `top` you have in `parent1` too... added snippet to the answer...

Comment: Thank you so much sir @kukkuz. I'll accept this later.